# Redux normalizr: simple example is not working with the latest version

Tags: redux, react-redux, normalizr

Here is the example from the github official documentation of [normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/tree/master) library. I am using latest version `3.2.4`.

**schema.js**

```
import { normalize, schema } from 'normalizr';

// Define a users schema
const user = new schema.Entity('users');

// Define your comments schema
const comment = new schema.Entity('comments', {
  commenter: user
});

// Define your article 
const article = new schema.Entity('articles', { 
  author: user,
  comments: [ comment ]
});

let originalData = {
  "id": "123",
  "author": {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Paul"
  },
  "title": "My awesome blog post",
  "comments": [
    {
      "id": "324",
      "commenter": {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Nicole"
      }
    }
  ]
}

const normalizedData = normalize(originalData, article);

console.log('NORMALIZED DATA: ', normalizedData)
```

and it results as follows,

[image]

Problem is that `comment` and `author` entities were not created. They are still nested in the `article`.

Here is my `package.json` file,

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/webpacker": "^3.0.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "form-serialize": "^0.7.2",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "normalizr": "3.2.4",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.3",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-select-plus": "^1.0.0-rc.5",
    "react-tooltip": "^3.3.1",
    "redux": "3.5.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "textile-js": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.7.1"
  }
}
```

I spend much time to figure out the issue with no luck. It seems, normalization working fine with the old version of library (Atleast, I checked with `2.3.0`).

Can someone help me with this problem? Is there anything wrong with the setup? or Do I need to install any dependencies?

Comment: I just copy pasted your code, run it and it works as expected without any issues

Comment: Thanks @NikitaU. Its strange. It did not work for me for some reason. I had to use old version of `normalizr 2.3.0`